# Displaying the most recent record

Tags: python, mongodb, jinja2, mongoengine

I have a MongoEngine object with a number of data entries, one data entry may contain 5 fields.

Using `Jinja2` how would I display only one of those fields, e.g. consider the following:

The field names are:

- schools
- studied_from
- studied_to
- qualifications
- fields_of_study

Now a user have 2 records of with the above fields, I only want to display one(the most recent), I currently have this:

```
Certified in {% if context.education|map(attribute="studied_to")|max %} // this gets the biggest date
    {{ context.education|map(attribute="fields_of_study")|first }} //I want to display only the field pertaining to the date displayed above.
{% endif %}
with
{% if context.job_history|map(attribute="industries")|first() == context.education|map(attribute="fields_of_study")|reverse()|first() %}
        {{ context.job_history|map(attribute="from_")-context.job_history|map(attribute="to_") }} // this is not running
        {% endif %}
experience
{{ context.education|map(attribute="studied_to")|max|datetime }}
...
```

Problem is that the most "most recent" fields_of_study wont always be first.

How can I display only the `most recent` record as shown above?

Comment: How do you determine which fields of study is the most recent?  Maybe add method to the model to get this information for you.

Comment: I determine the "most recent" by looking at the `studied_to` field, i.e. user a could have `studied_to: 2012/01/30` and `studied_to: 2015/01/30` I would use the 2015 one as the "most recent"

Comment: So you need to filter the list and get the latest out? I would add a method / property to your model

Comment: Pretty much, yes... Any hints on what this method / property would look like? Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but I am still learning...

Comment: @Renier can you provide example document of collection (or mongoengine class definition) and what is `context.education`? Do you really want to get max element in template instead of database (I'm sure database would make that much faster)?